# codename one: specify container size in mm?

Tags: codenameone, screen-density

I need to display a container in the same size in mm for every kind of mobile phone. I had the idea to get the display density and then to calculate the propper size in pixels. Therefor I searched for some method to get the display density and found the Method `getDeviceDensity()` in Class `Display`. But it does not return the real Pixel density at all. (This Problem was already discussed here.)
Does anybody know an other solution for my Problem?
Can I get the real density in a different way? Or do you know a kind of workaround to specify a component size in mm in codename one?
I'd be gratefull for some help!

Comment: You can use Display.convertToPixels(dipCount) where dips are approximately 1mm. I'm not sure if this actually is more accurate than what you tried already, but maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `calcPrefferedSize` in the container and as James mentioned return the value from `convertToPixels`.